# Wordpress function access through url

Tags: php, wordpress

Is there any option to access a function inside function.php through a url?

Like joomla [has this](http://www.example.com/index.php?option=com_users&controller=login&task=mytask).

Any idea?

Comment: Possible solution? http://stackoverflow.com/a/5414407/122005

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use ajax functionality of wordpress:

[HERE](http://codex.wordpress.org/AJAX_in_Plugins)

You can use `nopriv` actions for that.
`wp-admin/admin-ajax.php` is the url for the ajax page of wordpress.

**Or** either you can make a template page which gives only content and create a shortcode
and add to a specific page.

Answer (score 0):

functions.php is part of the core of your theme and is *automatically included*.

to access your function, simply use it in your theme file, as such:

```
<?php myfunc(); ?>
```